# Kibana UI fails to load for v7.0.0 with error "Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information" on s390x

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have instance of elasticsearch v7.0.0 running and when kibana v7.0.0 is started, the server logs show "Server running at http://localhost:5601" but the UI fails to load with error "Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information" .

Please help provide pointers on above issue. Thanks.

kibana server log:

```
log   [12:00:39.240] [info][status][plugin:maps@7.0.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [12:00:39.487] [info][license][xpack] Imported license information from Elasticsearch for the [monitoring] cluster: mode: basic | status: active
  log   [12:00:41.441] [warning][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [12:00:41.594] [info][status][plugin:reporting@7.0.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [12:00:41.634] [warning][reporting] The Reporting plugin encountered issues launching Chromium in a self-test. You may have trouble generating reports: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 1: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: cannot create qWqtq?q?q?q?qrr8rUrkryr?r?r?r?r?r?r?rs!s3sBsfs~s?s?s?s?sttAt?t?t?t?t?t?t?t?t?t?t?tuu:uKuYuqu~u?u?u?u?u?u?u?uv"v5vKvbvkvpvtvxv?v?vNw?????.???????)?B?S?c?w???????????????
??1?<?I?U?j?s?}?????¦¦%?/?;?L?o?w?~?????????????????????????????A??????????
                                                                         ??3?   ???"???5?<?F?P?q????ggm
vm
5?
??
??
??C?\v?!?[? D?!!P)T!!??!!??41!!???b!!?R?!!0??!!???.x!!?>??!@?: File name too long
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 1: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: l?l?l?l?l?l?l?p?pqqqqq: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 1: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: : not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 7: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: !!???: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 8: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: !!????: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 1: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell:ELF: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 9: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell:!!??*!!???Q!!?????!HY?: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 9: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: !!????!!X??!!p?N!!81??: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 10: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: ?: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 11: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: !!8??l!: not found
/home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: 1: /home/test/kibana-7.0.0-linux-x86_64/data/headless_shell-linux/headless_shell: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-6-7-enable-reporting/175074) is a discussion forum for this issue.

I was facing the same issue, what I did was added `libnss3` package on my ubuntu machine.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-dev
```

This helped me to get rid of the error.